# Drawing an hexagonal cone in TikZ 2D

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a hexagonal cone via 2D and **not** using `3d-plot` library.

I wish to achieve the following:

[image]

I have achieved the following so far:

[image]

I see there is lot of gap when connecting the corners. How do I fill/remove the gap.

Also, how do I make the first half segments of `hex1` dashed.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{hexagon/.style = {
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides = 6,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    draw
}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[hexagon,xscale=4,fill=gray!50] (hex1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[above=5cm of hex1,hexagon,xscale=3,fill=gray!10,ultra thick,draw=gray!40] (hex2) {};

    \draw (hex1.corner 3) -- (hex2.corner 3);
    \draw (hex1.corner 4) -- (hex2.corner 4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just add `outer sep=0pt` to hexagon style definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{hexagon/.style = {
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides = 6,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,          %  <---
    fill=#1}                %% <--- 
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[hexagon=gray!50, xscale=4] (hex1) at (0,0) {};
\node[hexagon=gray!10, xscale=3, draw=gray, thick,
      above=5cm of hex1] (hex2) {};
\foreach \i in {1,2}
    \draw[dashed]   (hex1.corner \i) -- (hex2.corner \i); %% <---
\path[dashed,thick,draw=gray]                             %% <---
        (hex1.corner 6) -- (hex1.corner 1)  --
        (hex1.corner 2) -- (hex1.corner 3);
\foreach \i in {3,...,6}
    \draw   (hex1.corner \i) -- (hex2.corner \i);         %% <---      
\path[thick,draw=gray]                                    %% <---
        (hex1.corner 3) -- (hex1.corner 4)  --
        (hex1.corner 5) -- (hex1.corner 6);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

edit: added answer on the second sub-question ...

Comment: thanks. Can you please answer the second query as well

Comment: i didn't understand the second question, however, now i see that you like to have all lines drawn and invisible should be dash lines ... i will do this asap :-)

Comment: @ subham soni, done!

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative in plain [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), just for comparison.

[image]

I thought a little rotation looked slightly more professional, but you could leave it out if you liked.  Note that the order of filling and drawing things is important in this diagram.  If you want real 3D I can recommend [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net).

Here is the source.  (Compile with `lualatex`).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path base, roof;

    base = (
        for i=0 upto 5: 
            89 right rotated 60i -- 
        endfor cycle
    ) rotated 8 yscaled 13/34;

    roof = base scaled 5/8 shifted 89 up;

    fill base withcolor 7/8 white;

    draw subpath (0, 3) of base dashed evenly;
    draw subpath (3, 6) of base;

    fill roof withcolor 15/16 white;

    for i=1 upto 2:
        draw point i of base -- point i of roof dashed evenly;
    endfor

    for i=3 upto 6:
        draw point i of base -- point i of roof;
    endfor

    draw roof;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative in which you can adjust the view angle etc.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{00}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={r1=3;r2=2.25;h=4;}]
 \path[fill=gray!50] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300}] 
 ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,dashed] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180}] ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0}] ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \foreach \X in {60,120,...,360}
 {\draw[thick] \ifnum\X<180 [dashed] \fi ({r1*cos(\X)},0,{r1*sin(\X)}) -- ({r2*cos(\X)},h,{r2*sin(\X)});}
 \path[fill=gray!25,fill opacity=0.8] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300}] 
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,dashed,gray!40] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180}] 
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,gray!40] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0}]
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]