# Drawing curved cone 3D

Tags: tikz-3dplot

How to draw curved cone in 3D with a given curvature or radius? Here is coding for straight cone.

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\def\RI{2}
\def\RII{1.25}

\draw[thick] (\RI,0)
  \foreach \x in {0,300,240,180} { --  (\x:\RI) node at (\x:\RI) (R1-\x) {} };
\draw[dashed,thick] (R1-0.center)
  \foreach \x in {60,120,180} { --  (\x:\RI) node at (\x:\RI) (R1-\x) {} };
\path[fill=gray!30] (\RI,0)
  \foreach \x in {0,60,120,180,240,300} { --  (\x:\RI)};

\begin{scope}[yshift=3.5cm]
\draw[thick,fill=gray!20,opacity=0.5] (\RII,0)
  \foreach \x in {0,60,120,180,240,300,360}
    { --  (\x:\RII) node at (\x:\RII) (R2-\x) {}};
\end{scope}

\foreach \x in {0,180,240,300} { \draw (R1-\x.center)--(R2-\x.center); };
\foreach \x in {60,120} { \draw[dashed] (R1-\x.center)--(R2-\x.center); };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @M.AlJumaily I'm sorry for accidentally rejecting [your edit suggest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/171211).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "curved cone"? Curvature is a tensor, so which edges should curved? BTW, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489173/121799) produces an almost identical picture and contains a complete code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code produces a truncated hexagonal cube, and I added some curvature.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{20}{00}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare
function={r1=2;r2=1.25;h=3;curvature=1;}]
 \path[fill=gray!50] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,dashed] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \foreach \X in {60,120,...,360}
 {\draw[thick] \ifnum\X<180 [dashed] \fi 
 plot[variable=\x,domain=r2:r1]
 ({(\x+curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2))*cos(\X)},{-h*(\x-r1)/(r1-r2)},{(\x+curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2))*sin(\X)});}
 \path[fill=gray!25,fill opacity=0.8] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300}] 
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,dashed,gray!40] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180}] 
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,gray!40] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0}]
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The mandatory animation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{20}{00}
\foreach \CC in {5,15,...,355}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\curvature}{sin(\CC)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare
function={r1=2;r2=1.25;h=3;curvature=\curvature;}]
\path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box] (-1.1*r1,{-1.2*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*r1})
 rectangle (1.1*r1,{h+1.2*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*r2});
 \path[fill=gray!50] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,dashed] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \foreach \X in {60,120,...,360}
 {\draw[thick] \ifnum\X<180 [dashed] \fi 
 plot[variable=\x,domain=r2:r1]
 ({(\x+curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2))*cos(\X)},{-h*(\x-r1)/(r1-r2)},{(\x+curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2))*sin(\X)});}
 \path[fill=gray!25,fill opacity=0.8] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300}] 
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,dashed,gray!40] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180}] 
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,gray!40] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0}]
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM** Everything bent in the same direction, which is given by `bd` in the following code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{20}{00}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare
function={r1=2;r2=1.25;h=3;curvature=1;bd=0;}]
 \path[fill=gray!50] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,dashed] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0}] 
    ({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});
 \foreach \X in {60,120,...,360}
 {\draw[thick] \ifnum\X<180 [dashed] \fi 
 plot[variable=\x,domain=r2:r1]
 ({\x*cos(\X)-curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2)*cos(bd)},{-h*(\x-r1)/(r1-r2)},
    {\x*sin(\X)-curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2)*sin(bd)});}
 \path[fill=gray!25,fill opacity=0.8] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300}] 
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,dashed,gray!40] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180}] 
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
 \draw[thick,gray!40] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0}]
 ({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. So great ! How to draw each edge is bent the same side ?

Comment: @nft What do you mean by this? This is a 3d picture. Do you want to bend every bent edge in the same direction?

Comment: Yes. It looks like an arc (a half circle) with the first and end sections are hexagonal sections.

Comment: @ntt I added something of that sort.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I want to rotate the top section 45 degree counterclockwise and the bottom section 45 degree clockwise (rotate w.r.t  z-axis). Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ntt Please ask a new question.