# How to draw a curved cone 3D with rotating sections

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to draw a curved cone 3D with the top and bottom sections are rotated 45 and -45. It seems not working since each edge does not connected to each other. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{20}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare
function={r1=2;r2=1.25;h=10;curvature=5;bd=0;}]

\path[fill=gray!50] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300},rotate around={-45:(0,0,0)}] 
({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});

\draw[thick,dashed] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180},rotate around={-45:(0,0,0)}] 
({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});

\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0},rotate around={-45:(0,0,0)}] 
({r1*cos(\x)},0,{r1*sin(\x)});


\foreach \X in {60,120,...,360}
{\draw[thick] \ifnum \X<180 [dashed] \fi 
    plot[variable=\x,domain=r2:r1]
    ({\x*cos(\X)-curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2)*cos(bd)},{-h*(\x-r1)/(r1-r2)},
    {\x*sin(\X)-curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2)*sin(bd)});}


\path[fill=gray!25,fill opacity=0.8,] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,...,300},rotate around={45:(0,h,0)}] 
({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,60,120,180},rotate around={45:(0,h,0)}] 
({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={180,240,300,0},rotate around={45:(0,h,0)}]
({r2*cos(\x)},h,{r2*sin(\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You apply a 2d rotation to a 3d object. This is one reason why it "does not work".

Comment: I mean that I just want to rotate the sections 45 and -45 with respect to z-axis. Can you fix it or do you suggest something? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be great if you disclose the source of your code. The above code was written [for a specific task](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491149/121799), for which it works. Here you need a slightly different approach.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{20}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare
function={r1=2;r2=1.25;h=10;curvature=5;bd=0;rot=0.125;}]

\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {60,120,...,360}
{\draw[thick] \ifnum \X<180 [dashed] \fi 
    plot[variable=\x,domain=r2:r1]
    ({\x*cos(\X)-curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2)*cos(bd)},{h*(1+rot*cos(\X))*(\x-(r1+r2)/2)/(r2-r1)},
    {\x*sin(\X)-curvature*(\x-r1)*(\x-r2)*sin(bd)})
    coordinate (b-\Y)
    ({r2*cos(\X)-curvature*(r2-r1)*(r2-r2)*cos(bd)},{h*(1+rot*cos(\X))*(r2-(r1+r2)/2)/(r2-r1)},
    {r2*sin(\X)-curvature*(r2-r1)*(r2-r2)*sin(bd)}) coordinate (t-\Y);}

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \path[fill=gray!50] plot[variable=\x,samples at={1,...,6}]  (b-\x);
 \draw[thick,dashed] plot[variable=\x,samples at={6,1,2,3}]  (b-\x);
 \draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={3,4,5,6}]  (b-\x);
\end{scope}

\path[fill=gray!25,fill opacity=0.8,] plot[variable=\x,samples at={1,...,6}] (t-\x); 
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={1,...,6,1}]  (t-\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]